# How to select by day of week in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

Is it possible to use a predicate in Core Data using the day of week on a Date attribute?

For example in SQL there is the DAYOFWEEK() function.

What I'm trying to do is get the average scores grouped by day of week where each object has a score attribute and a date attribute.

I've gotten my head around the grouping part, I just can't find any info on the day of week part.

Comment: In the end I just went with adding an integer field to the entity to store day of week. This enabled me to achieve what I needed to do.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a transient attribute to the core data entity. And then in the implementation file for the entity (NSManagedObject) you would write the custom code.

In the header file:

```
@property (readonly) NSString *weekDayText;
@property (readonly) NSInteger *weekDay; // use the number for sorting
```

In the implementation file:

```
- (NSInteger)weekDay {
    // get the date from attribute
    // you declared in the header file also
    NSDate *event = self.scoreDate;

    // do some kind of test to make sure it's not null

    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents =[gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:event];

    NSInteger day = [weekdayComponents weekday];
    // weekday 1 = Sunday for Gregorian calendar

    [gregorian release];

    return day;
}

- (NSString *)weekDayText {
    NSInteger day = self.weekDay;
    // now you would use some kind of locale to return the proper string
    // for each language 
    NSString *text = .... // need to implement

    return text;
}
```